# Calculate mode of a sequence of numbers without using arrays/vectors

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I'm a TA for an Introduction to MATLAB course, and the class has not yet learned the use of arrays (or in MATLAB, vectors). There is an exam coming up and one of the questions on the study guide is as follows:

[Tough problem]   A mode is the number in a sequence that appears the most number of times. A user is prompted to enter a sequence of non-negative numbers in non-decreasing order one-by-one. The user indicates the end of the sequence by entering a negative number. Write a script to obtain such user input and determine the mode of the sequence. If there are multiple modes, you may report any one of them as the mode. Do not use arrays. Below is an example run:

```
Determine mode of a set of nonnegative integers.
Use a negative number to quit.
Give me a number:  70
Another number not smaller than the previous: 71
Another number not smaller than the previous: 80
Another number not smaller than the previous: 80
Another number not smaller than the previous: 80
Another number not smaller than the previous: 91
Another number not smaller than the previous: 93
Another number not smaller than the previous: -1
  Mode is 80.
```

I've been thinking about it, but I can't come up with a good solution.
Does anyone know if there is a good way to solve this?

The only solutions I can come up with are ugly hacks that attempt to simulate the use of an array by other means, such as using a string with delimiters to simulate a dictionary-like object.

Comment: Wow, that's not a very good problem for a MATLAB course. One of MATLABs strengths is the ease of doing matrix and vector operations, so prohibiting the use of an array is like telling someone they're only allowed to use reverse gear in their car. I'd ask the professor who made that exam what they think the answer should be.

Comment: ...I only noticed the "non-decreasing" part *after* I wrote the above comment, so I guess the problem is a general programming logic exercise. Still, it's weird that vectors haven't been covered yet. That was practically day 1 material in the intro to MATLAB course I took.

Comment: @gnovice Oh ok, I feel a bit less dumb about not noticing it now. But yeah, this course is basically an intro to compsci which happens to be taught in Matlab, so it's analogous to putting off teaching arrays in an Intro to Java course or something similar.

Comment: I never like seeing code with input like this.  It is a complete pain to develop because every testing run you need to type in a bunch of numbers and I mess that up more often than my code is wrong.  When I get code like that, I just comment out the input statements and enter the variables directly in the code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key point here is "Another number not smaller than the previous:". That means the input sequence is always sorted, and if there are equal numbers they must appear next to each other. Assume only 1 mode is needed, it should be trivial to deduce it using the variables `current_mode_so_far`, `frequency_of_current_mode`, `input` and `frequency_of_input`.

Comment: Dang, I was just writing an answer like this, but you beat me to it.

Comment: This is a bit embarrassing, I completely glossed over the whole mention of numbers being non-decreasing. Darn, this problem is a lot less interesting than I thought it was.

Answer (score 5):

Clue: Since the input sequence is in non-decreasing order, you *know* that (in your example) once you have seen a number greater than `80`, you are never going to see an `80` again. So at that point you know exactly how many `80`s are in the sequence.

Perhaps you could remember that number and *clue ends here*

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the clue. I don't know how but I completely missed that while reading the question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to store the whole values (i.e. array or vector).

Since the elements come in monotonic fashion, you just keep the mode seen so far (and how many times it has appeared). If a new element overtakes the current mode, just replace it and the count.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work:

```
num = input('Give me a number: ');
mode = num;
prev = num;
n = 1;
bestn = -1;

while num > 0
    num = input('Another number not smaller than the previous: ');
    if num > prev
        %New number
        if n > bestn
            %New mode
            bestn = n;
            mode = prev;
        end
        n = 1;
    else
        n = n +1;
    end
    prev = num;
end

fprintf('Mode is %d',mode);
```